# get json data when refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

i have a blogging app that every post have their own unique permalink, for example `/post/Dh3hdjs*` where `Dh3hdjs*` is the unique permalink.My issue are when the post is successfully created it will redirect to the specific link like `/post/Dh3hdjs*` , but after i refresh the page it becomes a json file. this is what i have so far

## Nodejs(express.js)

```
app.get('/post/:permalink', contentHandler.displayPostByPermalink);
```

**displayPostByPermalink**

```
this.displayPostByPermalink = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
        var permalink = req.params.permalink;
        posts.getPostByPermalink(permalink, function(err, post) { //get post data 
                                                             //by using permalink
            "use strict";
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(200,post) //if success send the data to angularjs controller
        });
    }
```

**getPostByPermalink**

```
this.getPostByPermalink = function(permalink, callback) {
        "use strict";
        posts.findOne({'permalink': permalink}, function(err, post) {
            "use strict";

            if (err) return callback(err, null);

            callback(err, post); // if found any return post data
        });
    }
```

## Angularjs

```
function PostCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
$http.get('/post/' + $routeParams.permalink).
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.data =data;
    }).error(function(err) {
      alert("something wrong")
    });
}
```

## html

```
<div class='pure-u-1'>
<h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
<h2>{{data.preview}}</h2>
   {{data.content}}
</div>
```

work fine until i fresh the page,it will turn into json document

Comment: A simple solution can be to change server api path from '/post/:permalink' to '/api/post/:permalink' this will stop sending JSON docs and let the AngularJS take control on page refreshals. There is another technique to identify ajax requests: var is_ajax_request = req.xhr;

Comment: @Nitin... this work ! answer the question i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution can be to change server api path from '/post/:permalink' to '/api/post/:permalink' this will stop sending JSON docs and let the AngularJS take control on page refreshals.

There is another technique to identify ajax requests:

```
var is_ajax_request = req.xhr;
```

Key thing to identify ajax request is, same url can be used to run page and api.